# Core Image Filters to apply Curves to each RGB channel separately

Tags: ios, core-image, instagram, cifilter

I am trying to apply a tone curve to an image like it does in photoshop. You are able to create a separate curve for each of the RGB channels, but on the Core Image Framework you can pick one tone for the whole image using CIToneCurve.

Has anyone figured out a way to maybe chain these events together to be able to apply a different curve for each channel?

Any help is MUCH appreciated :)

Comment: you might want to take a peek at @BradLarson's GPUImage framework ... open source, uses OpenGL ES, and you can write your own custom shaders.

Comment: Im trying to avoid OpenGL and stick with CIFilters :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this a lot the best solution I found was as CSSmith stated in the comments... To transition my app to using Brad Larson's GPUImage framework. It worked much faster and had much more capabilities than CIFilters.

Comment: So you didn't find out if it was possible to archive the separate curves with CIFilter?

Comment: @Georg nope. This was a long time ago, but I ended up on GPUImage

Comment: I also had a look at it and it looks really nice. And (without having it benchmarked) it at least seems to be faster as well... Thanks anyway :)